# Create events from timestamp

Tags: python

maybe someone can help me with that:

I've got a DataFrame with TimeDeltas:

```
timestamp       Time_Delta 
01.12.2014 00:10     0     
01.12.2014 00:25     15   
01.12.2014 00:30     5    
01.12.2014 00:35     5    
01.12.2014 00:50     15   
01.12.2014 01:15     25
01.12.2014 01:20     5
01.12.2014 01:35     15
01.12.2014 02:05     30
01.12.2014 02:25     20
01.12.2014 02:30     5    
01.12.2014 02:35     5    
01.12.2014 02:40     5    
01.12.2014 02:50     10   
01.12.2014 03:15     25
01.12.2014 03:20     5    
01.12.2014 03:30     10  
01.12.2014 03:40     10   
01.12.2014 03:55     15   
01.12.2014 04:25     30
```

What i want is to create events if the TimeDelta is less or equal than 15 minutes and at least occurs three times in a row. It should look something like this:

```
timestamp      Time_Delta Event_Nr 
01.12.2014 00:10    0     
01.12.2014 00:25    15     1
01.12.2014 00:30    5      1
01.12.2014 00:35    5      1
01.12.2014 00:50    15     1
01.12.2014 01:15    25
01.12.2014 01:20    5
01.12.2014 01:35    15
01.12.2014 02:05    30
01.12.2014 02:25    20 
01.12.2014 02:30    5      2
01.12.2014 02:35    5      2
01.12.2014 02:40    5      2
01.12.2014 02:50    10     2
01.12.2014 03:15    25
01.12.2014 03:20    5      3
01.12.2014 03:30    10     3
01.12.2014 03:40    10     3 
01.12.2014 03:55    15     3
01.12.2014 04:25    30
```

Unfortunately my python skills yet are very weak, so it would be great if someone could help me with that!

Best regards

My code looks like this:

```
df1=DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=['Number_Timestamps', 'Event_Number'])
Event_Nr=0
index=0
cnt1=0
cnt2=0
for i in range(len(df.index)-1):
    if df.Time_Delta.values[i]<=15:
        cnt1=cnt1+1
        if (cnt1>=3) & (df.Time_Delta.values[i+1]<=15):
        cnt2=cnt2+1
        index=i-cnt2
    else:
        index=i-cnt2
        df1.Event_Number.values[index+2:i+1]=Event_Nr                      
        Event_Nr+=1
        cnt2=2
```

it works, but looks quite unreadable...

Comment: You have this data in a dict i believe?

Comment: or do you have 2 separate lists aligned respectively?

Comment: its all in one df or what did you mean?

Comment: pandas , is it?

Comment: Yes it's Panda dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the code, but just an approach to address this problem.

You should prepare a buffer variable (i.e., a list of rows) containing the processed rows for which you have not yet took a decision. When the decision is taken you have just to flush the buffer by putting its elements in the new DataFrame (or other type of data structure).

create for cycle processing all the rows, and two variables outside the cycle: a variable keeping the last known value of Event_nr, and the empty buffer.

when you process a single row in the for cycle, put it in the buffer. Then check (considering the delta value and all other your assumptions) if you can make a decision about (ALL) the rows you have put in the buffer so far.
If the decision can be taken, add these rows to the new DataFrame by editing the Event_nr value (if the conditions have been accomplished) and empty the buffer.
If the decision cannot be taken, continue putting the rows in the buffer and checking the conditions.